# Hoverfly Ktor client Apache Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, ktor, hoverfly

I tried to do unit test with Hoverfly to mock external API.

```
companion object {
    @ClassRule @JvmField
    val hoverflyRule: HoverflyRule = HoverflyRule.inSimulationMode(dsl(
            service("people.zoho.com")
                    .get("/people/api/forms/P_EmployeeView/records").queryParam("authtoken","TOKEN")
                        .willReturn(success("{test:test}", "application/json"))
    ))
}
```

When I use the Apache client with ktor, that doesn't work. But with another  client like khttp, it works. Any ideas why?

Comment: What's the behaviour? It throws an exception? Do you have a stacktrace or can provide additional information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup default system proxy in `Apache` config:
http://hoverfly.readthedocs.io/projects/hoverfly-java/en/latest/pages/misc/misc.html

example with `ktor(0.9.3-alpha-3)`:

```
class ApplicationMockupTest {
  companion object {
    @ClassRule
    @JvmField
    val hoverflyRule: HoverflyRule = HoverflyRule.inSimulationMode(
        dsl(
            service("people.zoho.com:443")
                .get("/people/api/forms/P_EmployeeView/records")
                .queryParam("authtoken", "TOKEN")
                .willReturn(success("{j:gr}", "application/json"))
        )
    )
  }

  @Test
  fun exampleTest() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val client = HttpClient(Apache.setupDefaultProxy())
    val token = "TOKEN"
    val url = "https://people.zoho.com/people/api/forms/P_EmployeeView/records?authtoken=$token"
    val requestString = client.get<String>(url)
    hoverflyRule.verifyAll()
    Unit
  }

  fun HttpClientEngineFactory<ApacheEngineConfig>.setupDefaultProxy() = config {
    customizeClient {
        useSystemProperties()
    }
  }
}
```